# How to open port 25 to send email from localhost on windows

Tags: php, windows, email, smtp

I need one help.I need to send email using Localhost on windows.When i typed the below command and check.

`telnet localhost 25` it gave me the following result.

```
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed
```

Please help me to open this port and send email successfully.

Comment: Do you have an smtp server running on port 25 on your machine? You don't need to open a port to access localhost

Comment: i have checked using `netstat -an` but did not find any port running on port 25.

Comment: There will only be an email server running on localhost if you install an email server ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to install an email server on your machine. You can try [hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/)